# Get Timestamp from Firestore databse

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I stored a timestamp in my firestore db but when I want to get the timestamp I get some numbers i can't explain. Maybe there is a special technique to get the timestamp from firestore in my vuejs app which I dont know.

My timestmp looks the following:

[image: Timestamp]

But if i put the following command to get my timestamp:

```
let ref = db.collection('profile').doc('profile_data')
ref.get().then(snapshot => {
  profile = snapshot.data()
  profile.id = snapshot.id
}).then( () => {
  console.log(profile.date_of_birth)
})
```

I get the following output: 063147682800.000000000 which has nothing to do with an timestamp.
Does someone know how to get a timestamp from my firestore db so that i get the following result: 1012086000000 (which is the one i used to set the date_of_birth)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is actually the internal representation of Firestore's [`Timestamp` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp).

If you want to get the value as milliseconds since the epoch, you can call `toMillis()` on the timestamp object.

So something like:

```
console.log(profile.date_of_birth.toMillis())
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks! That was the solution but still I don't know why.

Comment: It's encoded with Firestore's own format, which is NOT a string, and is NOT a Javascript date object.  It has much finer "grain" than a Javascript Date object for example.  The .toMillis() mentioned converts the Firestore Timestamp format essentially to Javascript Date object format.  The Console converts it for display before showing you.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp